# Change color of chosen vertex using OpenGL 4.5

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, glsl, vertex-shader

I am writing a program in C++ using OpenGL to insert and edit triangles based on user input. After a triangle is displayed on screen, the user can click on any vertex and decide what color to assign to it by pressing a numbered key. Each numbered key represents a color, 1 can be red, 2 can be blue, and so on through 9.

Right now I have code to identify which vertex in the VBO they have clicked on, but I do not understand what to do the vertex once I identify it. I know I can use glUniform3f, which I am using now, but that makes every triangle in the scene the same color.

Vertex Shader and Fragment Shader:

```
Program program;
const GLchar* vertex_shader =
        "#version 150 core\n"
                "in vec2 position;"
                "void main()"
                "{"
                "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
                "}";
const GLchar* fragment_shader =
        "#version 150 core\n"
                "out vec4 outColor;"
                "uniform vec3 triangleColor;"
                "void main()"
                "{"
                "    outColor = vec4(triangleColor, 1.0);"
                "}";
```

Do I need to create a second VBO for just colors? If so, how do I set up the code to use both of them? I am very new to OpenGL so anything helps.

Comment: Using VBOs is easy. You can just update the part of the buffer that has changed by `glBufferSubData`. If you prefer only uniforms then you must pass the selected vertex identifier (the position in its VBO) and use if in the vertex shader by comparing to `gl_VertexID`.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to create a second VBO for just colors? If so, how do I set up the code to use both of them? I am very new to OpenGL so anything helps.

Yes you can. But it is also possible to encode the vertex coordinates and the colors in one VBO.

Anyway you have to create a vertex shader which has a 2nd attribute beside from the vertex coordinates. This attribute is the color associated to the vertex coordinate. And has to be passed to the fragment shader (in the following [Raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are used):

*Vertex shader*

```
const GLchar* vertex_shader = R"(
#version 150 core

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 vColor;

void main()
{
    vColor      = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)";
```

*Fragment shader*

```
const GLchar* fragment_shader = R"(
#version 150 core

in vec3 vColor;

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(vColor.rgb, 1.0);
}
)";
```

*C++*

```
GLuint program = ...;

glLinkProgram( program );
GLint position_inx = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
GLint color_inx    = glGetAttribLocation(program, "color");
```

If you want to use 2 [Vertex Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) where the 1st contains the vertex positions whit the x and y coordinates and the 2nd contains the colors with the red, green and blue color channel, then the definition of the arrays of generic vertex attribute may look like this:

```
GLuint VBOpos = ....; // x0, y0,     x1, y1, ...
GLuint VBOcol = ....; // r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1, ...

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOpos );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( position_inx );
glVertexAttribPointer( 
    position_inx,
    2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, // 2 floats per coordinate
    0, nullptr );          // tightly packed

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOcol );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( color_inx );
glVertexAttribPointer( 
    color_inx,
    3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, // 3 floats per color
    0, nullptr );          // tightly packed
```

If you want to use 1 [Vertex Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object), which contains the x and y coordinates followed by the red, green and blue color channel, then the definition of the arrays of generic vertex attribute may look like this:

```
GLuint VBO = ....; // x0, y0, r0, g0, b0, x1, y1, r1, g1, b1, ...

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO );

glEnableVertexAttribArray( position_inx );
glVertexAttribPointer( 
    position_inx,
    2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,     // 2 floats per coordinate
    5 * sizeof(float),         // stride of 5 floats from one tuple to the next one
    (void*)0 );                // offset of the vertex coordinates is 0

glEnableVertexAttribArray( color_inx );
glVertexAttribPointer( 
    color_inx,
    3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,      // 3 floats per color
    5 * sizeof(float),          // stride of 5 floats from one tuple to the next one
    (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)); // offset of the color attribute is 2 * sizeof(float)
```

Comment: What is the significance of the GLuint program = ...; in your c++ section?

Comment: @BenReilly I don't understand your question. `program` is the named shader program object, of course. `program = glCreateProgram()`